# How to resize window to fit an element inside html

Tags: javascript

I am using the `resizeTo` function on `window` object inside javascript to resize my entire window to fit a div elements `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`.
here is the code:

```
function onSomeEvent(){
   const el = document.getElementBySomeWay();
   window.resizeTo(el.clientWidth, el.clientHeight)
}
```

I can see the resize happen, but the window size is significantly larger than the `clientWidth/Height` sizes. (around 100px). I can see that the `width` and `height` obtained from element are correct but the window size is larger.
PS:
running this inside electronjs and the same thing happens when I try to use `window.setSize` or `window.setBounds` apis. tnx in advance for suggestions

Comment: There are minimum window sizes for the main browser window. Are these popup windows? Do browsers even support those anymore?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey good point. by the way this is not a pop up window. as I said the whole thing is inside an electron app and a `browserWindow`. but since the same thing happens  everywhere I didn't bother with electron stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so that was weird!! apparently there is a thing (I really don't know if it's a bug) in `electronjs` that prevents the `zoomFactor` from getting reset on each launch. this is the related issue on github:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10572
You need to manually reset the zoomFactor by calling:

```
window.webContents.setZoomFactor(1.0)
```

and since I had changed the zoom factor once, I was stuck with a fixed zoomout!